Why does the FCM notification look and behave different when the app is in foreground vs background
The notifications behave appropriately when the app is in foreground mode. However, if the app is in background mode, the notification icon is re-set to its default and on click, only opens up the MainActivity.
Here is my code snippit:
class FirebaseNotificationService : FirebaseMessagingService(){

    @Inject
    lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreUtil
 override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)
        // Called when a new FCM message is received

        Log.d("Message Received", message.data.toString())
        // Create and display a notification
        sendNotification(this, message.data)
    }

   

}


@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity  : ComponentActivity()  {
 companion object {
        const val CHANNEL_ID = "my_notifications"

    }

 // Function to create a notification channel
    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name = "Management"
            val descriptionText = "Management Notifications"
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance).apply {
                description = descriptionText
            }
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

 
                createNotificationChannel()
}


}

Why would I be able to launch the Management Activity properly when I click on the notification in foreground mode, but not when I click it when the notification was received on background mode? Additionally, why is the notification small icon only set in foreground mode?

When your app is in the background, the data payload of the notification (the custom data fields you are sending) is delivered to the onMessageReceived method only for notifications with a data payload and no notification payload. If your message includes both (notification and data payload), the system handles the notification itself when your app is in the background, and your onMessageReceived method will not be called. This means your custom intent logic might not be executed, leading to the default or specified activity being opened instead.

@SHAHEENBSV What can I do so that it doesn't bypass onMessageReceived when the app is in background mode?

you should send push notification with only data payload

see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38795553/9515917

@SHAHEENBSV Does this still work when sending notifications with fcm v1? When we remove the notification field we are met with a payload format error.
